# Robocode troubles with execute

Tags: robocode

```
Hello. I don't understand why execute don't work in robocode. I use example like this. And also dont work any functions with set (setAhead, setTurnGUnRight, etc).
```

```
C:\robocode\robots\TestRobot\TestRobot.java:50: error: cannot find symbolexecute();^symbol:   method execute()location: class TestRobotC:\robocode\robots\TestRobot\TestRobot.java:56: error: cannot find symbolsetTurnGunRight(0);^symbol:   method setTurnGunRight(int)location: class TestRobotC:\robocode\robots\TestRobot\TestRobot.java:57: error: cannot find symbolsetTurnGunLeft(0);^symbol:   method setTurnGunLeft(int)location: class TestRobot[loading libs\robocode.jar(/robocode/Event.class)][loading /modules/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.class][total 723ms]3 errorsCompile Failed (1)
```

```
Im trying to use functions without set and execute. But I want to know what is the problem.
```

Im trying only standart functions